# How to translate "Universities are increasingly looking for" into Spanish

Tags: traducción, adverbios

I was trying to translate "universities are increasingly looking for students who study a language" but was confused about whether "universities are increasingly looking for" would translate to:

1. "los universidades están cada vez más buscando", or
2. "los universidades están buscando cada vez más",

or any other translation you may think is more appropriate.
Thanks!

Comment: Hello Rushil! Your options are both correct, though the first one sounds slightly better to me. Just note that "universidad" is a feminine word so it would be "las universidades".

Comment: 100% with Charlie. Language is not logical. Both options are more than ok and meaning is the same. Nevertheless, 2nd sounds a little better.

Answer (score 2):

One of the different meanings of ["demandar"](http://dle.rae.es/?id=C8drIhp) is

> Pedir, rogar.

Basically, "demandar / [hacer demanda](http://dle.rae.es/?id=C8W49JX%7CC8drIhp) (of something)" is to make

> Súplica, petición, solicitud.

And ultimately to search for (5th meaning of ["demanda"](http://dle.rae.es/?id=C8W49JX%7CC8drIhp)).

Thus you could say

> Las universidades (o el mercado laboral) cada vez demanda más XYZ
>
> Las universidades (o el mercado laboral) aumentan su demanda de XYZ
>
> Las universidades (o el mercado laboral) están aumentando su demanda de XYZ

or even

> Se ha disparado la demanda de XYZ en las universidades <sub>The demand of XYZ skyrocketed in universities</sub>

Answer (score 2):

Creo que el estilo más formal de transmitir la idea "Universities are increasingly looking for..." Podría ser

> Cada vez con mayor frecuencia; las Universidades prefieren Xxxxxx en los candidatos / aspirantes a ......

Otra alternativa igualmente entendible puede ser

> Más a menudo, las universidades buscan Xxxxx...

Indiscutiblemente las mejores traducciones que se me ocurren para *Increasingly* son **[cada vez] con mayor frecuencia** (en tono formal) el agregar *cada vez* enfatiza el incremento en el corto plazo, pero solo mencionando "con mayor frecuencia" tienes una traducción completa de "Increasingly_

o bien **Más a menudo/ Más seguido**, el primero es de uso más común en España y algunos paises sudamericanos mientras que Más seguido es de uso normal el Mexico y Centro América

Answer (score 1):

1. "Las universidades buscan cada vez más a alumnos que estudien un idioma"
2. "Cada vez más, las universidades buscan alumnos que estudien un idioma".
3. "Las universidades cada vez más buscan alumnos que estudien un idioma".

Puntos:

- Present in the sense of permanency, ("presente durativo"), since it is understood as a process that will last for a long time.
- In the first option, the "a" serves to distinguish between "they search more students" (quantity of students) from "they search more intensely students"
- Anyway I would not see much of an issue with using the "están buscando" form. But [Google says it is rather unusual](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=est%C3%A1n+buscando+cada+vez+m%C3%A1s%2Cbuscan+cada+vez+m%C3%A1s&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=21&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbuscan%20cada%20vez%20m%C3%A1s%3B%2Cc0)(and Google is always right).
- The three translation that I provided are by the order of my preference, but I would not fight much if someone prefered the second or even the third option.

Comment: IDIOMA!, la correcta traducción de language es idioma

Comment: @Mike - Sí.  O bien, *lengua*.

Comment: problemas de traducción:  tenemos muchos tanto sinónimos como falsos amigos que se confunden con otros sinónimos en el ingles que terminan confundiéndose en falsos amigos